# App only running on devices that were connected to laptop

Tags: android, installation, rsa

I have a problem with my app release.

If I have the phone connected to my laptop it asks if I want to share the RSA fingerprint like this:

[image: RSA]

After I click yes, I can run the build and install the app on the phone successfully. I can even build an APK, debug or release and install it on any phone that was connected to my PC and accepted the RSA key(4 devices).

When I try to install that APK on another phone(tested on 3 other devices). It installs the debug APK but just says my app has stopped working and if I install the release APK , it just simply doesn't install.

Is this a common issue, is there something I need to do first?

Comment: How are you trying to install?

Comment: Build->apk or signed apk
Then I try to install the apk

Comment: Look in the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) for the cause of the error. Edit your question with any details of the error, including a full stacktrace if one is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should allow the debugging option for your actual device. and always check the "Always allow this computer" and click okay.

UPDATE

Solution 1: uninstall the application in the device  and try to install it again

Solution 2: go build>Build APK> and copy the apk file. And distribute it to others.

Solution 3: try to generated signed apk.Check the signature both version.

[image: See]

Comment: Things is I don't want the person to connect, I want to share the apk with them and let them install it

Comment: do you send the apk to other people and their phone is old android version?

Comment: My app can run from 5.1 and up, and theirs is 5.1 and up

Comment: I already updated my answer and try it . Hope it works and resolve your problem.

Comment: sorry but it still doesn't work, I really don't know what the problem could be :(

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to build a signed apk before sharing. Instructions on how to sign your apk can be found here -> https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Comment: It does the same even with a signed apk